# When did Batman say that killing a killer doesn’t change the number of killers in the world?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification

There have been a lot of memes made on this quote by Batman, but where or when did he say this line?

> If you kill a killer, the number of killers in the world remains the same.

Comment: How about if you kill two killers?

Comment: He probably [never said that](https://www.reddit.com/r/DC_Cinematic/comments/4jcy0c/if_you_kill_a_killer_the_number_of_killers_in_the/d35letp/)

Comment: easy math dude. you kill a killer, and in the process you become a killer... but if Batman ever said it I have not the foggiest idea.

Comment: @ibid - What if you're already a killer?

Comment: Exactly its a flawed line. You may have already killed or be a serial killer. No Idea when he said it though..

Comment: I've seen a similar line been attributed to Churchill, but mostly by websites like _BrainMindInspirationQuote_ or whatever.

Comment: He probably said it in *Batman vs Superman*, which is why nobody remembers it

Comment: What if you're like Dexter?

Comment: I thought the default for all quotes was Einstein.

Comment: The quote is like saying that when a Canadian emigrates to the USA, the mean IQ of both countries is raised. It requires you to do some quick maths and logic thereby making it memorable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like this quote is falsely attributed to Batman.  It is also attributed to Winston Churchill, but there is no hard evidence, that I can find, that either one said this.

It appears someone at some point used a picture of Batman and stuck the quote in front of it. (At least that's what one guy blogged).

An example of how people do this is below:[image]

Comment: Yep. Never forget [Abraham Lincon's warning](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f8/f2/64/f8f264d56ce69c7f0ccd822bfd6dca34.jpg)

Comment: Ha! Yes, always believe "honest" Abe, especially when he gives advise on the internet!

Comment: Amusingly, that's not even a picture of Dumbledore (it's Gandalf).

Comment: @Kevin That's actually the point. There's a [whole genre of memes dedicated to such chicanery](https://img.memesuper.com/6f5d5c80decace8865f25137b927ab41_use-the-force-gandalf-use-the-force-meme_1024-590.jpeg)